# wordpress : how to change the display of meta on single custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, post, meta

I found code for displaying the meta terms of a custom post type.
but it shows the metas as a vertical list.
I want the code to show CPT meta in a row, instead.
any help please?
the code:

```
<?php
//get all taxonomies and terms for this post (uses post's post_type)
foreach ( (array) get_object_taxonomies($post->post_type) as $taxonomy ) {

  $object_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'all'));

  if ($object_terms) {

    echo '- '.$taxonomy;

    foreach ($object_terms as $term) {
      echo '<p><a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($term, $taxonomy)) .
           '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $term->name ) .
           '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a><p> ';
    }

  }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the HTML markup in your foreach loop, try removing the paragraph tags to something like:

```
foreach ($object_terms as $term) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a> ';
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply .. it worked .. but there is one more issue please. i need to put some characters between the terms such as, by example (keywords : consumer, marketing, global. - Proceeding : 2015), any suggestions please?

Comment: You can add extra text to appear between the terms after the </a> in the echo. E.g. if you wanted to add commas after each term, then change the end of your echo statement with something like '</a>, ';